# HealthKit doesn't display workout event names

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I want to write data to AppleHealth from my fitness app. So I create an HKWorkout sample, and add workout events there (e.g. Squat, Assisted dip, Barbell Curl).

Here is the way I create HKWorkoutEvent array

```
var workoutEvents = [HKWorkoutEvent]()
var metadata: [String: Any] = [:]
workoutEvents = workout.workoutExercises.map {
            metadata[HKMetadataKeyWorkoutBrandName] = $0.exercise.name
            
                return HKWorkoutEvent(
                    type: .segment,
                    dateInterval: DateInterval(start: $0.timeStartedDate, duration: 60.0 * 6),
                    metadata: metadata
                )
        }
```

And here is the way I create single HKWorkout event

```
     let hkworkout = HKWorkout(
        activityType: .traditionalStrengthTraining,
        start: startDate,
        end: endDateUsing,
        workoutEvents: workoutEvents,
        totalEnergyBurned: caloriesBurnt,
        totalDistance: nil,
        totalSwimmingStrokeCount: nil,
        device: .local(),
        metadata: nil)
```

And then I save that workout like this

```
HKHealthStore().save([hkworkout]) { success, error in }
```

My problem is when I head to Apple Health app, and read records from my app, there are no exercise names displayed. Instead I see only "Segment" word related to each workout, which is very frustrating for the user I guess, as he would probably like to see which workout he spent time on, etc.

See screenshot attached below

[image]

So I guess HKWorkoutEvent does not read data from `HKMetadataKeyWorkoutBrandName` value and sets "segment" word for all the workout events.

Is there any way to have actual workout event name displayed in Apple Health?

Comment: [This article](https://www.hung-truong.com/blog/2019/05/03/making-a-zwift-clone-part-3/) suggests that the undocumented metadata key `"Segment Name"` is what you want

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your finding, but unfortunately it doesn't work either, and each workout event name is still Segment..